# rosjava for arm navigation

Tags: arm-navigation, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to rosjava (and ros) and am trying to control a robotic arm using joint control and rosjava. I am able to do this with c++ using the follow_joint_trajectory/goal topic and a FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal message. However, I have not been able to find an equivalent class in Java (the FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal.java is an interface). Are there any tutorials that anyone can point me to or can someone point me to the appropriate message to send? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33042/rosjava-for-arm-navigation/) by [Steveb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2079/steveb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

actionlib isn't yet supported in the most recent version of rosjava.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0